# Problems with compiling an iOS build with cordova

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I'm having problems trying to compile the iOS build with cordova.

While trying to compile/build a cordova app for iOS get the following error and can't successfully generate a build. Has anyone seen this error before and can help diagnose the problem? I can not get it to build on a physical device, I can successfully deploy to the emulator but I get this error for a physical device.

I think it has something to do with a device specific error, iPhone 5S running on IOS 11. I'm currently stumped and do not know where to proceed or continue from this point.

Stack trace copy:

```
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image: Stack trace error]

Answer (score 0):

1. This error generally occurs when you have linked any library or file twice.For example, in my project I had some class files duplicated.In the error description, the name of the duplicated file will be listed, you can search and and make sure you don't have duplicates for e.g. in Your case search for “CDVLogger”,Just look and remove extra classes. Problem will be solved.
2. Another way to getting this error if  you used the Xcode recommended warning flags. GCC_NO_COMMON_BLOCKS = YES was causing the issue. Setting this back to NO fixed the problem.
3. Finally clean and run the Project.